# how to call View controller of MainStoryBoard from UI cellView xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

The problem i want to call view controller of MainStoryBoard. 
i have created UIcellView in xib file and on that have button so  i want to move on **AddLocationVC** viewController when i pressed the button.

I have written some code

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:Nil];

AddLocationVC *view = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddLocation"];
```

its not worked when i pressed the button its does not redirect me on view controller **AddLocationVC** but controller is coming in this section of code.

Comment: Tell your exact problem.You did not ask correctly which you want.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way of doing this would be to use `protocols` or `blocks`. With `delegate protocol` the steps would be:

1. Define a `DelegateProtocol` in your custom cell `class`
2. In `cellForItem/RowAtIndexPath:` make your `ViewController` the `delegate` of your cell and implement the `protocol` in it. Here you'll instantiate the new `ViewController` and present/push it
3. On button tap call the `delegate` method